# Что можно сделать умного если в конструктор передан объект того же типа?

Tags: python

Есть класс и в его конструктор может быть передан объект того же класса. Можно ли как то не конструировать новый объект, а вернуть тот что был передан?

Comment: А можно пример? Проверить объект на принадлежность к классу и вернуть его.

Comment: Так, может, не передавать в конструктор объект, если он уже есть?

Comment: В этом и проблема что я не знаю в каких местах вызывается конструктор. А можно же как-то по умному скопировать? Не итерируясь по всем полям переданного и не вызывая setattr для текущего.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно.

```
class Test:
    def __new__(cls, obj=None):
        if isinstance(obj, Test):
            return obj
        return super().__new__(cls)
```

Но зачем? Конструктор для того и существует чтобы создавать ***новый*** экземпляр класса.